# C# Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

Console.WriteLine = cw на клавиатуре, а
 Console.ReadLine = ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229103/keyboard-shortcut-for-c-sharp-console-class/32229312

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.